# Applying transition on flexbox justify-content property

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a CSS class that on hover should change the `justify-content` property from `center` to `flex-start` with a delay of 1s.

So everything works fine and is being delayed except from the `justify-content`.

```
.menuItem:hover {
    transition-property: all;
    transition-delay: 1s;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? And If so, how can I achieve that behavior?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 34):

`justify-content` is not a transition-able property. You can find the full list of compatible properties [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties). All unlisted properties should simply snap to their new value.

If you happen to need to animate a single element only, you may try using absolute positioning.

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

#element {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    transition: all 300ms;
}

#element:hover {
    left: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

> Keep in mind that this will **not** work for multiple elements.

Comment: @Pachu I have updated my answer with a workaround - given that you only have a single element to animate.

Comment: Hi, I have found a way that works perfect which is not a workaround, I have added an answer, I will up vote your answer because you helped me figure another way.

Comment: Nice alternative behavior. Thanks!

Comment: It is shame `justify-content` does not support tweens with transitions. Based on this answer I've put together a codepen that creates an animation using `.scss` to calculate where the element's stopping point. https://codepen.io/csalmeida/full/WLOvJw

Comment: Don't trust this solution, translateX will move it's content but it will keep using the space on the right, so if you have a button placed right under #element it wont be clickeable

Answer (score 17):

You can achieve your goal with two flex items, where the transition is on the "flex" property.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid orangered;
}

.dummy {
  flex: 0;
  transition: flex 1s;
  border: 1px solid limegreen;
}

.container:hover .hovered {
  flex: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="content"> hover over me </div>
  
  <div class="dummy hovered" />
  
</div>
```

Hey Fabricio, this section is for your question. Cheers

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.content {
  width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid orangered;
}

.dummy {
  transition: flex 1s;
  border: 1px solid limegreen;
}

.after {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.before {
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.container:hover .before {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="dummy before" ></div>

  <div class="content"> hover over me </div>
  
  <div class="dummy after" ></div>
  
</div>
```

Hey Robo, this section is for your notice. Flex-grow is not the only possible way. At least flex-basis can also do the job. I haven't tried with flex-shrink but can see the possibility too.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
 
.content {
  max-width: fit-content;
  min-width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid orangered;
}

.dummy {
  flex-basis: 0;
  transition: flex 1s;
  border: 1px solid limegreen;
}
  
.container:hover .dummy {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">hover over me</div>
  <div class="dummy" />
</div>
```

Comment: I like your solution (voted it up), but can you do the other way around (which is what I need here)? I tried reverse-engineering your technique, and I managed to make it animate the text from left to centre, but unfortunately it jumps back to the left (without animation) once I hover the mouse out. :(

Comment: @Fabricio Hi mate, I've just added another example above for your question.

Comment: It has an extra `div` but I can use it. Good work around. Thanks, mate!

Comment: It's worth saying that what it actually transitions is `flex-grow`.

Comment: @RoboRobok Flex-grow is not the only possible way. At least flex-basis can also do the job (see example above). I haven't tried with flex-shrink but can see the possibility too.

Answer (score 1):

You can't animate 'justify-content', but if you need to animate element to move from one side to other, you can do:

```
.parent {
   display: flex;
}

.menuItem:hover {
  flex: 1;
  animation: moveAnim .3s alternate 1;
}

@keyframes moveAnim {
  from { flex: none }
  to{ flex: 1 }
}
```